# Action Mailer breaks application when attempting to send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

Looking for help with the action mailer in rails. I'm using Rails 3.2 and devise for authentication. I followed the railscasts to get started on using the action mailer so I'm setting up the action mailer for my first time and ran into some issues. I've set devise's registration controller to send out an email when registering. What's happening is the application is breaking when it hits that line of code to send out an email. I'm including my logs, action mailer, etc below for help....Thanks for the help

**Development Log**

```
Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-04 15:36:11 -0600
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"EWH87yAT4dTuK12kZ27HiidVzGZAhx+sHa4N2rXIWIM=", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"john", "lastname"=>"doe", "email"=>"[FILTERED]", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "store"=>{"storename"=>"Store 1"}, "commit"=>"Create my Account"}
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
  [1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.5ms)[0m  SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = BINARY 'david.gilbert@visibleequity.com' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO `users` (`admin`, `created_at`, `current_sign_in_at`, `current_sign_in_ip`, `email`, `encrypted_password`, `firstname`, `last_sign_in_at`, `last_sign_in_ip`, `lastname`, `owner`, `remember_created_at`, `rentor`, `reset_password_sent_at`, `reset_password_token`, `sign_in_count`, `updated_at`, `userimage`) VALUES (0, '2012-08-04 21:36:11', NULL, NULL, '[FILTERED]', '$2a$10$yXNkAXglLgZBBPkDmE/T2uShDtgXeRO3ka1mXhUxwzTABgp.8Ijle', 'john', NULL, NULL, 'doe', 0, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, 0, '2012-08-04 21:36:11', NULL)[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `stores` (`created_at`, `storeimage`, `storename`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('2012-08-04 21:36:11', NULL, 'Store 1', '2012-08-04 21:36:11', 118)
  [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
  Rendered user_mailer/signup_confirmation.text.erb (0.4ms)
```

**Server Log**

```
Served asset /head_transpar.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
/Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:583: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0107 p:---- s:0530 b:0530 l:000529 d:000529 CFUNC  :connect
c:0106 p:0059 s:0527 b:0527 l:000526 d:000526 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:583
c:0105 p:0255 s:0522 b:0521 l:000b70 d:000b70 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:560
c:0104 p:0047 s:0513 b:0513 l:000512 d:000512 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:519
c:0103 p:0668 s:0506 b:0506 l:000505 d:000505 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:144
c:0102 p:0031 s:0495 b:0495 l:000494 d:000494 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2034
c:0101 p:0009 s:0491 b:0491 l:000467 d:000490 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229
c:0100 p:0021 s:0489 b:0489 l:000471 d:000488 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:414
c:0099 p:0017 s:0486 b:0486 l:000476 d:000485 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123
c:0098 p:0032 s:0484 b:0484 l:000483 d:000483 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20
c:0097 p:0036 s:0477 b:0477 l:000476 d:000476 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123
c:0096 p:0021 s:0472 b:0472 l:000471 d:000471 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionmailer-3.2.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:412
c:0095 p:0039 s:0468 b:0468 l:000467 d:000467 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/mail-2.4.4/lib/mail/message.rb:229
c:0094 p:0091 s:0465 b:0465 l:000464 d:000464 METHOD /Users/dave/rails_projects/EquiptMe/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:6
c:0093 p:0014 s:0462 b:0462 l:000461 d:000461 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4
c:0092 p:0015 s:0456 b:0456 l:000455 d:000455 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167
c:0091 p:0041 s:0451 b:0451 l:000450 d:000450 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10
c:0090 p:0010 s:0447 b:0447 l:001a20 d:000446 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18
c:0089 p:0192 s:0445 b:0445 l:000444 d:000444 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436
c:0088 p:0112 s:0439 b:0439 l:000438 d:000438 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405
c:0087 p:0027 s:0430 b:0430 l:000429 d:000429 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385
c:0086 p:0024 s:0425 b:0425 l:000424 d:000424 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0085 p:0020 s:0419 b:0419 l:001a20 d:001a20 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17
c:0084 p:0012 s:0415 b:0415 l:000414 d:000414 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29
c:0083 p:0010 s:0410 b:0410 l:000391 d:000409 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30
c:0082 p:0017 s:0406 b:0406 l:000396 d:000405 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123
c:0081 p:0032 s:0404 b:0404 l:000403 d:000403 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20
c:0080 p:0036 s:0397 b:0397 l:000396 d:000396 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123
c:0079 p:0152 s:0392 b:0392 l:000391 d:000391 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29
c:0078 p:0143 s:0387 b:0387 l:000386 d:000386 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205
c:0077 p:0032 s:0381 b:0381 l:000380 d:000380 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18
c:0076 p:0093 s:0376 b:0376 l:000375 d:000375 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121
c:0075 p:0084 s:0370 b:0370 l:000369 d:000369 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45
c:0074 p:0048 s:0365 b:0365 l:000364 d:000364 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203
c:0073 p:0086 s:0360 b:0360 l:000359 d:000359 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14
c:0072 p:0030 s:0354 b:0354 l:000928 d:000353 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246
c:0071 p:---- s:0351 b:0351 l:000350 d:000350 FINISH
c:0070 p:---- s:0349 b:0349 l:000348 d:000348 CFUNC  :call
c:0069 p:0022 s:0345 b:0345 l:000344 d:000344 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66
c:0068 p:0094 s:0339 b:0339 l:000338 d:000338 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30
c:0067 p:0026 s:0333 b:0333 l:000332 d:000332 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40
c:0066 p:0184 s:0329 b:0329 l:000312 d:000328 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68
c:0065 p:---- s:0318 b:0318 l:000317 d:000317 FINISH
c:0064 p:---- s:0316 b:0316 l:000315 d:000315 CFUNC  :each
c:0063 p:0051 s:0313 b:0313 l:000312 d:000312 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56
c:0062 p:0025 s:0309 b:0309 l:000308 d:000308 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:570
c:0061 p:0015 s:0305 b:0305 l:000304 d:000304 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-pjax-0.5.9/lib/rack/pjax.rb:12
c:0060 p:0014 s:0297 b:0297 l:000288 d:000296 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35
c:0059 p:---- s:0295 b:0295 l:000294 d:000294 FINISH
c:0058 p:---- s:0293 b:0293 l:000292 d:000292 CFUNC  :catch
c:0057 p:0086 s:0289 b:0289 l:000288 d:000288 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34
c:0056 p:0015 s:0284 b:0284 l:000283 d:000283 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17
c:0055 p:0015 s:0277 b:0277 l:000276 d:000276 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23
c:0054 p:0052 s:0269 b:0269 l:000268 d:000268 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35
c:0053 p:0093 s:0262 b:0262 l:000261 d:000261 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14
c:0052 p:0046 s:0255 b:0255 l:000254 d:000254 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21
c:0051 p:0054 s:0250 b:0250 l:000249 d:000249 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242
c:0050 p:0031 s:0242 b:0242 l:000241 d:000241 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205
c:0049 p:0013 s:0234 b:0234 l:000233 d:000233 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200
c:0048 p:0020 s:0230 b:0230 l:000229 d:000229 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338
c:0047 p:0064 s:0222 b:0222 l:000221 d:000221 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64
c:0046 p:0029 s:0213 b:0213 l:000212 d:000212 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:4
c:0045 p:0014 s:0205 b:0205 l:001da0 d:000204 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28
c:0044 p:0040 s:0203 b:0203 l:000202 d:000202 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405
c:0043 p:0112 s:0196 b:0196 l:000195 d:000195 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405
c:0042 p:0027 s:0187 b:0187 l:000186 d:000186 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385
c:0041 p:0024 s:0182 b:0182 l:000181 d:000181 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81
c:0040 p:0013 s:0176 b:0176 l:001da0 d:001da0 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27
c:0039 p:0039 s:0172 b:0172 l:000171 d:000171 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65
c:0038 p:0044 s:0167 b:0167 l:000166 d:000166 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31
c:0037 p:0017 s:0163 b:0163 l:000162 d:000162 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16
c:0036 p:0017 s:0156 b:0156 l:000155 d:000155 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56
c:0035 p:0121 s:0150 b:0150 l:000149 d:000149 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26
c:0034 p:0052 s:0144 b:0144 l:000143 d:000143 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16
c:0033 p:0048 s:0140 b:0140 l:000139 d:000139 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22
c:0032 p:0095 s:0133 b:0133 l:000132 d:000132 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21
c:0031 p:0032 s:0128 b:0128 l:000127 d:000127 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17
c:0030 p:0057 s:0119 b:0119 l:000118 d:000118 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activesupport-3.2.0/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72
c:0029 p:0068 s:0115 b:0115 l:000114 d:000114 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15
c:0028 p:0124 s:0109 b:0109 l:000108 d:000108 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53
c:0027 p:0032 s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:479
c:0026 p:0034 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:220
c:0025 p:0015 s:0095 b:0095 l:000094 d:000094 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14
c:0024 p:0015 s:0086 b:0086 l:000085 d:000085 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14
c:0023 p:0020 s:0081 b:0081 l:000072 d:000080 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80
c:0022 p:---- s:0079 b:0079 l:000078 d:000078 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 CFUNC  :catch
c:0020 p:0135 s:0073 b:0073 l:000072 d:000072 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78
c:0019 p:0088 s:0068 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53
c:0018 p:0036 s:0064 b:0064 l:000063 d:000063 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38
c:0017 p:---- s:0059 b:0059 l:000058 d:000058 FINISH
c:0016 p:---- s:0057 b:0057 l:000056 d:000056 CFUNC  :run_machine
c:0015 p:0248 s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256
c:0014 p:0066 s:0047 b:0047 l:001320 d:001320 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61
c:0013 p:0143 s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159
c:0012 p:0081 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13
c:0011 p:0271 s:0034 b:0034 l:000290 d:000290 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:265
c:0010 p:0231 s:0028 b:0028 l:0010c0 d:0010c0 METHOD /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70
c:0009 p:0063 s:0024 b:0024 l:000015 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:55
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0702 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    /Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:002678 d:000108 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:002678 d:002678 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dave/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/g
```

**Registration Controller**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.build_store(params[:store])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.signup_confirmation(@user).deliver
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user, :flash => {:success => "Welcome to the App"}
    else
      render 'new'
      @title = "Sign up"
    end
  end
end
```

**User Mailer**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "johndoe@gmail.com"

  def signup_confirmation(user)
    @user = user

    mail to: user.email, subject: "Thank You for Registering with us"
  end
end
```

**Development Environment**

```
Outdoor::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  #SMTP 
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :user_name            => 'Mygmail Account',
  :password             => 'MyPassword',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }


  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Comment: This is quite a frustrating bug. I hope someone can solve it!

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of strange that in you development log didn't have much about the error, because it should be (and I do hope you are not missing the latter part of your log file).

And also most common mistake would be not setting up the SMTP settings correctly.

And just turn on your mail delivery errors (config/environments/development.rb)

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

and following is a sample setting which used by me, with Gmail

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
                    :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
                    :port           => 587,
                    :authentication => :plain,
                    :user_name      => "sameera207@gmail.com",
                    :password       => "<my gmail password>",
                    :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
  }
```

Comment: I tried using what you have here but it still broke my app. I've changed the errors to = true...but stil nothing...I also think it's strange that I don't get anything more in the log.